# When you move Tkinter windows stops program

Tags: python, tkinter, urllib2

Hi
I made a music downloading program that works great it tells you the percent its done and then if i move the window at all it stops downloading .
I made a diffrent little script that downloads a specified mp3 on the web and i can move it as much as i want and it doesent stop.

the only reason im not putting up the code is that it is really long. Its around 1500 lines. Here is the small script that i made to download one file.

does any one know why it stops the program from working?
the little script:

```
from Tkinter import *
from urllib2 import *
admin = Tk()
Admin = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(admin, bg="PURPLE")
listbox.pack()
def __init__(self, master):

        def replay():
            Admin.destroy()
            os.system('WhaleWire.exe')

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()




        image1 = PhotoImage(file="whalewire.gif")
        w = image1.width()
        h = image1.height()

        master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

        # tk.Frame has no image argument

        panel1 = Label(master, image=image1)
        panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')

        panel1.image = image1
        self.e = Entry(frame)
        self.e.grid(row=0, column=0)



        b = Button(frame, text='Search', command=self.whale)
        b.grid(row=0, column=1)
        def library():
            path = 'C:\WhaleWire\Downloaded'
            aw=[]
            for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path,'*.mp3') ):
                libr = infile.split('Downloaded',1)


                aw.append('\n')
                aw.append(infile)
                la = Label(Admin,width=100,height=50, text=aw).grid(row=0,column=7)
                b2s = Button(Admin,text='Search', command=replay).grid(row=0,column=8)
        b11 = Button(frame, text='Library', command=library)
        b11.grid(row=0, column=3)   
def fores():
    chunks = 10000
    dat = ''
    song = '3 rounds and a sound'
    url = 'http://bonton.sweetdarkness.net/music/Blind%20Pilot%20--%203%20Rounds%20and%20A%20Sound.mp3'
    down = urlopen(url)
    downso = 0
    tota = down.info().getheader('Content-Length').strip()
    tota = int(tota)
    while 1:
        a = down.read(chunks)
        downso += len(a)

        if not a:
            break
        dat += a
        percent = float(downso) / tota
        percent = round(percent*100, 1)



        listbox.insert(END, percent)
        listbox.update()
        listbox.delete(0, END)
        listbox.insert(END, percent)
        listbox.update()





button = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=fores)
button.pack()
button = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=fores)
button.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: so... you're showing us a program that works, and from that we're supposed to guess how the program you don't show us fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem is because you are calling `update`. You should never do that unless you know for certainty what the ramifications are. `update` causes a new event loop to be entered. Essentially, you end up with an infinite loop inside an infinite loop.

Try changing your `update` to `update_idletasks` and see if that solves your problem. This variation of `update` only processes "idle" events such as screen redraws and is considerably less likely to cause problems.

Also, you definitely don't need "update; insert; delete; update". That won't have any noticeable effect. A single call to `update_idletasks` after the delete is sufficient.

Finally, you can avoid the use of `update_idletasks` completely by rearranging your code. Write a function that reads a single chunk of data and updates the progress bar. Then, if it hasn't reached EOF, use `after` to call that function again a few milliseconds later. When it reaches EOF it stops calling itself. Doing this means you don't have to create your own potentially infinite loop, and the event loop is guaranteed to be entered once per iteration. Once this EOF is detected you can then call a function (again using `after`) to do any final processing.